# Can bigquery save queries as .sql files locally?

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I do not know how to do that, as i would like to upload the code to github. Would appreciate some guidance thank you. :)

Comment: See [Google BigQuery export manual](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data)

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to export saved queries programmatically right now.

But there is an issue pending for this feature:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970?pli=1

But since the last year, you were able to use scripts as Stored Procedures to execute and do this kind of approach.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures